# How to execute a C++ console program in a C++ program?

Tags: visual-c++

I've already tried system() and spawnl, but strangely, the .exe program that I've tried to execute within my C++ program didn't work as it should be.

### this is my piece of code:

```
    #include <stdio.h> 
    #include <process.h> 

    int main(void)
    {
    puts("Executing simpleTest.exe...."); 
    spawnl( P_WAIT, "C:/simpleTest.exe",
    "C:/simpleTest.exe", "Using spawnl", "Arg1", "Arg2", NULL );
    system("pause");  
    return 0;
    }
```

---

that simpleTest.exe is actually a C++ console application too, and I want to invoke it within a C++ console application named Invoke.exe....I wonder if that's what my problem is.
If I execute simpleTest.exe by double-clicking it, it works fine....but if I execute it with above code, it exits because it encounters an error...
I wonder where did I do wrong? Is there any other suggestion beside above code?
Oh yeah, I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 by the way...
Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the Current Working Directory is not what simpleTest.exe expects?

Answer (score 0):

The MSVC (Windows actually) way to execute a process is via CreateProcess function. I've never used spawnl however, so I don't know how it works.

Comment: Doubly so since spawnl was deprecated in VS2k5, from memory.

Comment: Deprecated in favor of `_spawnl`. Same function, just prepended with underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Using native C runtime process-creation functions would eventually call `CreateProcess` only. They may also create a console window, which may not be desirable.
Therefore, it is recommended to use `CreateProcess` or `ShellExecute` family of functions.